If possible how can I expand a JSON string field in one Delta Live Table into another Delta Live Table?
I have a Delta Live Table (DLT) with a string column that contains a serialized JSON object. I'm trying to create another DLT that queries from this table with some filtering, parses the JSON, and creates a new DLT from the resulting object (properties become columns), inferring the schema.
I've tried all sorts of things (from_json, parse_json, json.loads...) but nothing works for various different reasons. The closest I've gotten is just using dataframes, something like:
<sql query to get json data>

...

df = _sqldf.rdd.map(delta: row.JsonData)
spark.read.json(df).show()

But this obviously isn't a DLT. I've tried in both SQL (create of refresh streaming table ...) and Python and can't figure out how to do it, if it's possible.

Provided solution kindly check it. @Josh

Below are the possible solution.
If you are having the schema or sample json then you can use the below code.
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, schema_of_json

sample_json = '{"property1": "value1", "property2": 2, "property3": {"sub_property1": "sub_value1"}}'

json_schema = schema_of_json(sample_json) #You can also directly use the schema if it is available.

@dlt.table
def parsed_json_table():
    
    df = spark.table("default.your_source_table")
    parsed_df = df.withColumn("parsed_json", from_json(col("JsonDataColumn"), json_schema))
    final_df = parsed_df.select("parsed_json.*")
    
    return final_df

In the above code, a schema is created using the sample json and parsed.
You can also directly use the schema if it is available.



id
JsonDataColumn




1
{"property1": "value1", "property2": 2, "property3": {"sub_property1": "sub_value1"}}


2
{"property1": "value2", "property2": 3, "property3": {"sub_property1": "sub_value2"}}


3
{"property1": "value3", "property2": 4, "property3": {"sub_property1": "sub_value3"}}



Output for above input.



property1
property2
property3




value1
2
{"sub_property1":"sub_value1"}


value2
3
{"sub_property1":"sub_value2"}


value3
4
{"sub_property1":"sub_value3"}



If you don't have sample json or schema then try below approaches.
Your source json data having the constant schema through all the records then take a sample one and generate schema.
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, schema_of_json


@dlt.table
def parsed_json_table():
    
    df = spark.table("default.your_source_table")
    sample_json = df.select("JsonDataColumn").limit(1).collect()[0][0]
    json_schema = schema_of_json(sample_json)
    parsed_df = df.withColumn("parsed_json", from_json(col("JsonDataColumn"), json_schema))
    final_df = parsed_df.select("parsed_json.*")
    
    return final_df

If the schema varies from record to record, then you need to create a standard schema for all the records manually and parse it using from_json(col("JsonDataColumn"), json_schema)
Sample code to create schema.
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType


json_schema = StructType([
    StructField("property1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("property2", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("property3", StructType([
        StructField("sub_property1", StringType(), True)
    ]), True)
])

